# Absolute position button (& center modal that it's in)

Tags: css, button, modal-dialog, absolute

I can't figure out how to get the button in this modal to behave like I want. I need it 20px from the bottom of the modal (and of course centered.)

The modal itself also doesn't seem to be centered. Please help me do that too.

I will put the url in the comments.

Just click the "Meet your sponsor" button at the top of the site, to open the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outer `<div>` wrapping the `<button>` and add the following css to your button class i.e. `.md-content button`.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0; (instead of left: 109.2px; used by you)
right: 0;
```

the whole class looks like this :

```
.md-content button {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh. Thank you so much, that fixes the button! <3 (Although I don't know what you mean about me having 109.2px there previously... I couldn't find that anywhere.) But it's positioned correctly now. The only other thing now is: centering the modal itself. It seems to be pushed to the right more. Can you help me center it?

Comment: Nvm, I got it. Modal is centered now, so this is done. :p